# Error en card de Material-Ui - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando la librería de [MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com) y quiero utilizar un card.
He copiado exactamente el segundo ejemplo (Complex Interaction) de [cards](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) y al probarlo local aparece:

```
 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

Tengo todas las dependencias instaladas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que modifiqué del código del ejemplo fue el nombre de la clase y la imagen de la tarjeta.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import ShareIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Share';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500],
  },
}));

function PropiedadCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  function handleExpandClick() {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  }

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="Recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
        subheader="September 14, 2016"
      />
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
        title="Paella dish"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
          This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook together with your
          guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the mussels, if you like.
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to favorites">
          <FavoriteIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="Share">
          <ShareIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
          })}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="Show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add saffron and set aside for 10
            minutes.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet over medium-high
            heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook, stirring occasionally until lightly
            browned, 6 to 8 minutes. Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken
            and chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic, tomatoes, onion, salt and
            pepper, and cook, stirring often until thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add
            saffron broth and remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a boil.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Add rice and stir very gently to distribute. Top with artichokes and peppers, and cook
            without stirring, until most of the liquid is absorbed, 15 to 18 minutes. Reduce heat to
            medium-low, add reserved shrimp and mussels, tucking them down into the rice, and cook
            again without stirring, until mussels have opened and rice is just tender, 5 to 7
            minutes more. (Discard any mussels that don’t open.)
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes, and then serve.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default PropiedadCard;
```

Creo que el error puede ser por que no estoy exportando `useStyles`...
Cómo debería resolverlo?

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "deprops",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "clsx": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-fb-image-grid": "^0.1.5",
    "react-images": "^0.5.19",
    "react-photo-gallery": "^7.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.1",
    "react-youtube": "^7.9.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "watch": "react-scripts start --watch"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrás adjuntar el `package.json` para ver qué dependencias usas? Más que nada para ver la versión instalada de material-ui.

Comment: Editado, la version es:  "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés un problema de versión, en la página que estás viendo y copiando el ejemplo es de la versión `4.0` para arriba, mientras que tu versión es la `3.9.3`. Para eso, en la página tenés una forma de ver cómo se arma el ejemplo para esa versión. Este sería la url de la [documentación de cards](https://v3-9-0.material-ui.com/demos/cards/).

Por ende, la estructura del ejemplo cambia bastante, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = {
  card: {
    minWidth: 275,
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
};

function SimpleCard(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
          Word of the Day
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
          be
          {bull}
          nev
          {bull}o{bull}
          lent
        </Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
          adjective
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">
          well meaning and kindly.
          <br />
          {'"a benevolent smile"'}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}

SimpleCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```